# Remote debugging Docker container with ptvsd doesn't stop on breakpoint

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I try to debug program which is launched on Docker container using VS Code and ptvsd.

Debugger configuration:

```
"name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
"type": "python",
"request": "attach",
"port": 9091,
"host": "localhost",
"pathMappings": [
    {
       "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
       "remoteRoot": "/usr/src"
    }
]
```

File which should be debugged:

```
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('0.0.0.0', 9091))
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()

while True:
    print('elo') # breakpoint is set here
```

I run container with open port 9091 and code inside container. Then start debugger.
Debugger is attached but it doesn't stop on breakpoint and runs infinite loop.

ptvsd is installed on local and remote with the same version - 4.2.7

What should be changed to make debugger stop on breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, but here the work around.
Try the following:-

```
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach(address=('0.0.0.0', 9091))
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()

while True:
    breakpoint() #this command will add the breakpoint which will detected by debugger
    print('elo')
```